# Bootstrap - responsive mobile view display first the sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I currently have the following website: http://flagshub.com/

I want to show the sidebar first, and only after the content in mobile view. What change I need to do in my html code? I am using bootstrap as site framework.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order using Bootstrap `push` and `pull` classes. In your case, it will be:

```
<aside class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">...</aside>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">...</div>
```

More info here: [enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Comment: Thank you, but that will also affet the order in non-mobile view, in normal computers...

Comment: @xohubigimu What is the order you need in desktop version? sidebar and main content or main content and sidebar?

Comment: desktop: 1st: main, 2nd sidebar; mobile: 1st: sidebar, 2nd main

Comment: @xohubigimu OK. I edit the code. See above. You need to change the content order in your file.